# Why TYPO3 calls a wrong File Reference table

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have a Model for a Products table with this code to get the images references:

```
/**
 * Returns the images
 *
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference $images
 */
public function getImages() {
    $fileRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileRepository::class);
    $this->images = $fileRepository->findByRelation('tx_myext_domain_model_products', 'images', $this->uid);
    return $this->images;
}
```

But it triggers an error:

```
ERROR => 'Table 'database.tx_core_resource_filereference' doesn't exist'
```

Don't sure why this table name is used. `sys_file_reference` is the name of the real table in the database.

Comment: Your code seems to be copied from documentation ( https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/ExamplesFileFolder.html#getting-referenced-files ) and so, it should be working.
Maybe tx_myext_domain_model_products.images has a strange configuration in TCA?

Answer (score 1):

If this is in the domain as you suggested, then all you should need is:

.../Classes/Domain/Model/Product.php

```
...

  /**
   * images
   *
   * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
   */
  protected $images = null;


  /**
   * Returns the images
   *
   * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference images
   */
  public function getImages()
  {
      return $this->images;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the images
   *
   * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $images
   * @return void
   */
  public function setImages(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $images)
  {
      $this->images = $images;
  }

...
```

Then the TCA for products would require config for images... for example:

.../Configuration/TCA/tx_yourext_domain_model_product.php

```
...


        'images' => [
          'label' => 'FAL Image',
          'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'images',
            [
              'appearance' => [
                'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
              ],
              // custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
              // to use the image overlay palette instead of the basic overlay palette
              'overrideChildTca' => [
                'types' => [
                  '0' => [
                    'showitem' => '
                    --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                    --palette--;;filePalette'
                  ],
                  \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                    'showitem' => '
                    --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                    --palette--;;filePalette'
                  ],
                ],
              ],
            ],
            $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
          ),
        ],

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you use a wrong `FileReference`. Check if you import the correct one in your Model:

**Wrong:**

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference;
```

**Correct:**

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference;
```